# Parent height based on relative positioned children

Tags: html, css, css-position

css is a **marvelous** thing except when you are blocked and you haven't had your *ahaha moment*.

Today I am having trouble to **scale the height** of my parent div containing a **relative positioned** element to the proper height. This is because the children is using a `top` property.

Now I know how `top` works on relative positioned element and I understand why it does not contains the proper height value.

What I want to know is:
"Is it possible to **include this top property in the height of my parent** without switching to paddings or margins ?"

Here is a fiddle of my code: http://cssdeck.com/labs/unfeydw0
Or a simple code below:

*html:*

```
<div>
    <div class="relative">
    </div>
</div>
```

*css:*

```
.relative {
    position: relative;
    top: 42px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you specify "top" you will move your object always without affecting parent's height. Which means that if you want to affect it's height you will have to move it with margins.

So your answer is: "No it is not possible". Here is the specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#Computing_heights_and_margins

Comment: So even if I wrap this relative child with others div / positions there is no way for me to match parent height to children height + top ?

Answer (score 6):

I found that what worked for me in a similar situation was instead of setting `top:` I set `margin-top:`. That will cause the parent div to resize itself appropriately.

Comment: Exactly this is what I was looking for in Feb 2021..

Answer (score 0):

You could add an empty element after the `.relative` and set it's `height` to that of the `.relative`'s `top` positioning.

Comment: I saw this answer on another similar question but I was wondering if there was some other tricks at our disposal.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass it with jquery

```
var positionToTop = $(".relative").css("top");
$(".relative").parent().css({"top":positionToTop});
```

i [forked a CSSDeck](http://cssdeck.com/labs/gcdvzpyf) here for you