# Relative Container Position Bug

Tags: html, css

If using the relative positioning keeps my content box within the body container, why does the box I am using overlap the body tag's borders?

This is the html:

```
<body>

    <div class="content">
        <img src=""/>
    </div>

</body>
```

This is the css for my body tag:

```
body { 
    font-family: Calibri;
    background-color: #e7e6e8;
    width: 100%;
    min-height:100%;
    min-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    border: solid black 5px;
    }
```

This here is the trouble maker:

```
.content {
    position: relative;
    width: 1325px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 45px;
    left: 7%;
    border: solid black 2px;}
```

Comment: which should be the expected result?

Comment: sorry, i just ran the html and css on a notepad, the content container fits in the body. But, that's only if i use just those two together. But for some reason on my entire html and css code, when i have other containers there, they overlap. Why is this the case? They as in the content box and the bottom border of the body tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `margin-top: 45px;` instead of `top: 45px;`. (Also `margin-left: 7%;` if you want to stop the overflow there as well.)

If you relatively position an element, it's always doing so after setting the height/width of it's parent. More in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15136825/6153889)